# Who/what aborted job during its exectution on jenkins?

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

A job a started on the jenkins is sometimes aborted. If I understand it correctly, the job can only be aborted by a user.

If my assumption is correct, I would like to know which user aborted my job ( they might have a good reason ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the job page, click on the link to the job # that got aborted (on the left side).

The page that opens normally displays artifacts, graphs, etc.

This page, near the bottom, should have an

`"Aborted by user <user>"`

Also, if you use the [Audit Trail](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+Trail+Plugin) plugin, it will log all this information in the log file you specify.